# Is stored procedure calls in mysql on linux are slower than on windows?

Tags: mysql, linux, database, windows, performance

I am trying to run a stored procedure in mysql on Linux and found it very slow whereas the same stored procedure call is very fast in mysql on Windows machine. To be precise, It takes 28 seconds on Linux and 1.5 seconds on Windows. So, I wanted to know is there any specific configuration to be made on Linux machine to make it behave normal as in Windows.

Indexes are same on the tables in both the systems. And in-fact the records are more in Windows machine than in Linux, so Windows machine should have seen bit slower than Linux.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you confirm this occurs in a simple example that can be easily duplicated by other readers?

Comment: You compared all of `SHOW VARIABLES`?  Especially `LIKE '%buffer%'`?